# How to run sql-postgres without password?

Tags: sql-interactive-mode

My PostgreSQL authenticates using Unix Domain Sockets (Trust Authentication). When I run `psql` I do not need a password to connect to the database.

But when I run `sql-postgres`, I am always asked for a password. How can I tell Emacs, that I have no password?

Comment: How does psql know the socket to use?  (echo $PGPORT might tell you think if you don't know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I got it myself.

I had to set server to `/var/run/postgresql` in the customization of `sql-postgres-login-params`.

```
'(sql-postgres-login-params
  (quote
   ((user :default "xxx")
    (server :default "/var/run/postgresql")
    (database :default "xxx"))))
```